# Connecting newly created mysql database using jdbc driver in netbeans

Tags: mysql, jdbc, netbeans

Please Please Help me to resolve the problem

When am trying to connect mysql database using netbeans, following error is shown that

> Cannot establish a connection to `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/netbeanstest`
>    using `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` (Unknown database)

I searched for the solution in stackoverflow, but my problem still exists.
I checked my jdbc driver, password, username everything is correct.
Checked the privileges of the database to confirm the username and password.

And when I connect the inbuilt databases like `'mysql'`,`'information schema'`, connection is successful.

Please help me to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your url, you specified:  jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/netbeanstest

do does your db have 'netbeanstest' schema? if not than create netbeanstest schema and than try to connect

Comment: thanks for your reply.
'netbeantest' is the database name

Comment: So, you tried after creating that schema, and does that exists

Comment: yes
I got the solution. When I stop all services in wamp server, then I can connect the database. Thanks for your support